Fluctuating electric field or Johnson noise inside a cavity
I have read that "power is dissipated by the thermal motion of electrons in an imperfect conductor, and these fluctuating currents imply the presence of fluctuating electromagnetic fields in the interior of the cavity" from the HAYSTAC axion search. I want to obtain the expression for the electric field in the TM mode due to this thermal noise; however, I am not sure how I can find it using Klein-Gordon equation. Is there a noise term on RHS or a boundary condition I have to use? (temperature is known)

Where did you read it? Could you provide your source?

It is from  arXiv:1801.00835 page 124

I see you referenced the right-hand-side (RHS). That generally refers to an equation: all things right of the "=" sign. Do you see the problem?

I would use the in-homogeneous Helmholtz wave equation for the electric field with your noise model.

Without alluding to the linked arxiv, if the noise in the EM field inside the cavity is generated entirely by the random thermal equilibrium motion of electrons in the cavity's walls, then the spectrum (and modes) of the noise must be the same as black body radiation, whose derivation is readily available in most textbooks.

Blackbody radiation is indeed mentioned in the paper, but I am stuck on using it to get the field generated inside a cavity. Also, I am not trying to get the total energy. I just want the electric field inside the cavity. Wave equation with different modes can be used but I am not sure about the exact form of the boundary condition.
